# Control factor mixing vectors (Animation nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to add some random location to a circualar array in animation nodes.
The goal is to keep the cubes in the circle.
But I don't know how to control the factor like when using a mix shader in material nodes.

[image]

[image]

When using 'project', the cubes are placed in within the outer circle. But then there then I also need to clamp somehow to prevent the cubus going inside each other in the middle.

[image]

I believe both these options can be solved using the right node? Like a 'map range' node but that one won't connect.

The end result should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the cubes do move only radially like if it were on a bicycle wheel spokes https://www.campagnolo.com/media/immagini/7630_n_BORAultra35-ant-2018.jpg or can they move independentely on the disc, as long as they are within the bounds ?

Comment: Hi Gorgeous, posted this in a new question because I think it is another topic and because I didn't want to bother you more with my beginners level haha. You are exactly right with the bicycle wheel spokes, when that's set I want to mix the result of that with some random vector influence. I will add a picture of the result in the question now.

Comment: For people to want to do a similar thing and need the base too. Gorgious helped me with the base. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181350/random-around-empy-animation-nodes/181359?noredirect=1#comment303948_181359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set max and min vectors then mix it using random numbers,

[image]

Comment: Superb, thank you Hari Sreedhar!